digikam stopped working in the last week. F40 on WSLg on Win10
I recently installed digikam on a WSL Fedora instance on my Win10 home desktop. It ran beautifully for a few days - long enough to get my entire collection of 100,000 images scanned and indexed. But after a dnf update a few nights ago, I get a segment fault somewhere in KDE initialization. I don't know if this is peculiar to WSLg or to a version update in some of the KDE libraries (kf6, qt6) in general.
Anyone else seen problems in this area beginning around 2024-12-12 ?
